# Why Is Flask Not Returning JSON To User's Browser In My Chatbot App?

Tags: python, jquery, flask, dialogflow-es

I've been working through the following tutorial:
https://pusher.com/tutorials/chatbot-flask-dialogflow

It is for a simple, flask chatbot app where a user asks for details about a movie.

The user's request is then sent to Dialogflow API. DialogFlow deciphers the user's intent and then sends a JSON POST request to flask /get_movie_detail.

Here, flask connects to the IMDB API and retrieves details about the movie the user is interested in.

The movie details should then be returned to the user.

The app works fine up until the point the movie details should be returned to the user but for some reason this part is not working:

[image]

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import os
import dialogflow
import requests
import json


def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, text, language_code):
        session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
        session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

        if text:
            text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
                text=text, language_code=language_code)
            query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
            response = session_client.detect_intent(
                session=session, query_input=query_input)



            return response.query_result.fulfillment_text


credential_path = "/Users/will/Documents/Laura/movie_bot/movie-bot-twrobf-6efd82e3249a7.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path            

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/get_movie_detail', methods=['POST'])
def get_movie_detail():
    data = request.get_json(silent=True)
    movie = data['queryResult']['parameters']['movie']

    api_key = 'ac95c504'

    movie_detail = requests.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={0}&apikey={1}'.format(movie, api_key)).content

    movie_detail = json.loads(movie_detail.decode('utf-8'))


    response =  """
            Title : {0}
            Released: {1}
            Actors: {2}
            Plot: {3}
        """.format(movie_detail['Title'], movie_detail['Released'], movie_detail['Actors'], movie_detail['Plot'])


    reply = {
            "message": response
        }

    return jsonify(reply)


@app.route('/send_message', methods=['POST'])    
def send_message():
    message = request.form['message']
    project_id='movie-bot-twekbf'
#    project_id = os.getenv('DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID')
    fulfillment_text = detect_intent_texts(project_id, "unique", message, 'en')
    if fulfillment_text:        
        response_text = { "message":  fulfillment_text }    
        return jsonify(response_text)
    else:
        return jsonify({"message": "bear with me..."})

# run Flask app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Also, here is the jquery code that handles the json responses and displays them in the browser

```
function submit_message(message) {
        $.post( "/send_message", {message: message}, handle_response);

        function handle_response(data) {
          // append the bot repsonse to the div
          $('.chat-container').append(`
                <div class="chat-message col-md-5 offset-md-7 bot-message">
                    ${data.message}
                </div>
          `)
          // remove the loading indicator
          $( "#loading" ).remove();
        }
    }


// /static/custom.js

    $('#target').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const input_message = $('#input_message').val()
        // return if the user does not enter any text
        if (!input_message) {
          return
        }

        $('.chat-container').append(`
            <div class="chat-message col-md-5 human-message">
                ${input_message}
            </div>
        `)

        // loading 
        $('.chat-container').append(`
            <div class="chat-message text-center col-md-2 offset-md-10 bot-message" id="loading">
                <b>...</b>
            </div>
        `)

        // clear the text input 
        $('#input_message').val('')

        // send the message
        submit_message(input_message)
    });
```

I know that flask is successfully retrieving the movie details from IMDB because if I add print movie details to my code, as show below:

```
    movie_detail = json.loads(movie_detail.decode('utf-8'))


    response =  """
            Title : {0}
            Released: {1}
            Actors: {2}
            Plot: {3}
        """.format(movie_detail['Title'], movie_detail['Released'], movie_detail['Actors'], movie_detail['Plot'])


    reply = {
            "message": response
        }


    print(response)
    return jsonify(reply)
```

... The expected movie details are displayed in my IDE.

[image]

However, for whatever reason the movie details are not being returned to the browser with

```
return jsonify(reply)
```

Also, I am testing the app locally, when I check Chrome Developer tools, it seems /get_movie_detail is not returning anything to the browser:

[image]

Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check `print(jsonify(response_text))` ? Did you check JSON data in browser ? Maybe browser gets it but JavaScript doesn't add to page ?

Comment: What you return is JSON, but only on the outer level. The data itside is a large string.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the JSON you're returning doesn't match the JSON format Dialogflow is expecting. It looks like you mixed up the JSON that `get_movie_detail()` and `send_message()` should be sending.

The `send_message()` function is called in a later part of the tutorial, and isn't related to Dialogflow.

Instead, Dialogflow is configured to call `get_movie_detail()`. The lines that setup the `reply` variable should be setting a parameter named `fulfillmentText`. It should look something like this:

```
    reply = {
        "fulfillmentText": response,
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Prisoner that was a mistake on my part. i mixed up the code that get_movie detail and send message. I have updated the post accordingly.

it seems that dialogflow is successfully sending the json response to get_movie_detail via webhook and /get_movie_detail is successfully getting the movie details from IMDB however for whatever reason movie_detail is not successfully returning the response back to the browser. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm very confused. The code *still* shows `get_movie_detail()` returning the wrong thing. So when your browser calls `/send_message` which runs `send_message()` and calls Dialogflow which calls `get_movie_detail()` - the result it gets back doesn't have `fulfillmentText` set because you didn't set it. (If your code really does set it - show that. Because right now, that looks like the problem still.)